# Como cerrar un modal con ESC en Angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs

los molesto para consultarles si tienen idea de como hacer para que se cierre una ventana modal cuando el usuario presiona la tecla Escape. 
Tengo hecha la función close, para cuando el usuario presiona un botón "Cancelar", por lo que mi pregunta central seria, como puedo hacer para captar el evento de que un usuario presiona la tecla ESC (Escape) y de esa manera utilizarlo para cerrar el modal. Esto en **Angularjs**.
Desde ya les agradezco por su tiempo.

Comment: ya que no pones el codigo ni nada, usa window.addEventListener('onkeyup', function(event){ /* codigo */ })

Comment: Revisa [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470790/how-to-use-a-keypress-event-in-angularjs), te puede servir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para las cerrar una ventana modal con angularjs, simplemete debes definir tu configuracion de modal en tu controller con: "escapeToClose: true"
ejemplo de archivo de configuracion en el controller:

```
var config = {
    attachTo: angular.element(document.body),
    controller: PanelDialogCtrl,
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    disableParentScroll: this.disableParentScroll,
    templateUrl: 'panel.tmpl.html',
    hasBackdrop: true,
    panelClass: 'demo-dialog-example',
    position: position,
    trapFocus: true,
    zIndex: 150,
    clickOutsideToClose: true,
    escapeToClose: true,
    focusOnOpen: true
};
this._mdPanel.open(config);
};
```

Aqui un ejemplo de como hacerlo en codepen https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true